# How to pass a table name to a function in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have various settings tables in Excel, each with two column headings Parameter and Value.

I want to pass a specific table's name to a function `getParameter` that looks up a specific parameter's name in that table, returns the associated parameter's value, and performs all error handling, e.g. with the following code segment:

```
Function getParameter(....  
...  
Dim paramterValue as Variant  
With Application  
    parameterValue = .Index([tableName[Value], .Match("parameterName",  [tableName[Parameter], 0))  
    If Not IsError(parameterValue) then  
        ...  
    Else  
        ...  
    End If  
End With

End Function
```

How do I define the appropriate function arguments and call the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables are in `VBA` selectable as [ListObject Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197604.aspx). But those objects are on worksheet scope only. So we must know the worksheet on which the table is placed on to get it using `wrksht.ListObjects(tableName)`.

To be more flexible, we could using `Evaluate` to evaluate the structured references:

```
Public Function getParameter(tableName As String, parameterName As Variant) as Variant

Dim parameterValue As Variant
Dim oRangeTValues As Range
Dim oRangeTParameters As Range

Set oRangeTValues = Evaluate("" & tableName & "[Value]")
Set oRangeTParameters = Evaluate("" & tableName & "[Parameter]")
With Application
    parameterValue = .Index(oRangeTValues, .Match(parameterName, oRangeTParameters, 0))
    If Not IsError(parameterValue) Then
        getParameter = parameterValue
    Else
        getParameter = CStr(parameterValue)
    End If
End With

End Function
```

This will be usable on all worksheets since the table names are on workbook scope in reality.

This is supposed to be used as User Defined Function using a cell formula like `=getParameter("TableName","Parameter")`.

Comment: You would need to make this Volatile because there is no parameter giving the Table reference: would be better to pass the Table reference rather than Name.

Comment: @Charles Williams:Yes, maybe this needs to be set volatile depending of its usage. But the question was exactly "How to pass a table name to a function?" and not "How to pass a table reference to a function?" For the latter there is no `VBA` needed. This can be achieved using Excel's  native `INDEX` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try like this, identifying the sheet and the ListObject corresponding to your `TableName` :

```
Function getParameter(ByVal tableName As String, ByVal parameterName As String) As Variant
Dim parameterValue As Variant
Dim RgVal As Range
Dim wS As Worksheet
Dim LOTable As ListObject

Application.Volatile

Set wS = Evaluate(tableName).Parent
Set LOTable = wS.ListObjects(tableName)
Set RgVal = LOTable.DataBodyRange

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    parameterValue = .Index(RgVal.Columns(2), .Match(parameterName, RgVal.Columns(1), 0))
End With 'Application.WorksheetFunction

If Not IsError(parameterValue) Then
    getParameter = parameterValue
Else
    '...
    DoEvents
    getParameter = CStr(parameterValue)
End If

End Function
```

Call in VBA :

```
Sub test_GetParameter()
    Debug.Print getParameter("Table1", "testParam")
End Sub
```

Call in Excel :

```
= getParameter("Table1", "testParam")
```

Comment: You would need to make this Volatile because there is no parameter giving the Table reference: would be better to pass the Table reference rather than Name.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams : Isn't `Set LOTable = wS.ListObjects(tableName)` enough to get the table ref?

Comment: Yes but (assuming this is being used as an UDF) unless you pass a reference to the table as a parameter Excel will not recalculate the UDF when data in the table changes.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams : Thx, I didn't thought of that use! Will edit in a bit! ;)

Comment: @Cyberpro : If your issue is solved, please accept an answer!

Answer (score 0):

@R3uk Axel Richter's code is sufficient, but yours also works.